# Why background images of buttons are changing for last list item's button only,when I click on any list item's button?

Tags: java, android

I have created list view with adapter class, in which in list item, i have given three buttons. I need to change background image of that button and other button also. I have 5 list items and every items has its own buttons.

Now, as I click on first, second up to fifth list item's buttons, background of last image is changing only. Every list item's button's background image should change if I click on respective button depend on logic. It is happening for only last list item..

Please help me if anyone knows how to do this..

Code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

}

private void init() {

    LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
    View view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.datelabel, null);

    setListAdapter(new EventListAdapter(this));     

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tapped on position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{  
    ((EventListAdapter)getListAdapter()).toggle(position);

}
private class EventListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int VISIBLE = 0;


    private static final int GONE = 8;


    private TextView textViewForDateHeader;
    private TextView textViewTitle;
    private TextView textViewDialogue;

    private TextView textViewHeader;




    private ImageButton buttonForCheckMark;


    private ImageButton buttonForDelete;


    private View buttonForRemainder;



    public EventListAdapter(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.length;
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View myView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);           
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);


        textViewTitle = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewTitle.setText(mTitles[position]);

        textViewDialogue = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDialog);
        textViewDialogue.setText(mDialogue[position]);
        textViewDialogue.setVisibility(mExpanded[position] ? VISIBLE : GONE);

        buttonForCheckMark = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonForCheckMark);
        buttonForCheckMark.setVisibility(mExpanded[position] ? VISIBLE : GONE);

        buttonForDelete = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonForDelete);
        buttonForDelete.setVisibility(mExpanded[position] ? VISIBLE : GONE);

        buttonForRemainder = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonForRemainder);
        buttonForRemainder.setVisibility(mExpanded[position] ? VISIBLE : GONE);

        buttonForRemainder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tapped on remainder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        buttonForCheckMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tapped on checkMark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                buttonForCheckMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                buttonForDelete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_navigation_cancel);
                buttonForCheckMark.setClickable(false);
                buttonForDelete.setClickable(true);
            }
        });
        buttonForDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tapped on delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                buttonForCheckMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_navigation_accept);
                buttonForCheckMark.setClickable(true);
                buttonForDelete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
                buttonForDelete.setClickable(false);
            }
        });


        return myView;
    }


    public void toggle(int position) {


        mExpanded[position] = !mExpanded[position];
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    /**
     * Remember our context so we can use it when constructing views.
     */
    private Context mContext;


    /**
     * Our data, part 1.
     */
    //      private ImageButton[] mButtons = {
    //
    //              "R.drawable.remainder",
    //              
    //      };
    private String[] mHeader = 
        {
            "12 Jan, 2013",   
            "13 Feb, 2013",
            "31 Mar, 2013",       
            "15 Aug, 2013",
            "7 Sep, 2013"

        };


    /**
     * Our data, part 1.
     */
    private String[] mTitles = 
        {
            "Event 1",   
            "Event 2",
            "Event 3",       
            "Event 4",
            "Event 5"

        };

    /**
     * Our data, part 2.
     */
    private String[] mDialogue = 
        {
            "wuszuogwfuieffufuhuysugdueljwihadghgxdhgyhghsdgyigwuweyuqaGDHGYHGHGAdhgyhigxgxgeuyehu.",
            "dgusduugyujguegytgujgdugwjhiuyg7wtqUYGYYgyijyiufufjguhgdugfhgfhgfgfhgfhghfghifgyi,dgwsdtgyfytfiuwt,",
            "rtygygghtudggyjhgujtugdhhguyuaUUUUDJYUIDHUJHDIIDUJDHDUJHDIDIOUYhujtdugyhdgg",
            "gjhuwjsgudggdudgjqhasdgdhgjdhushjaguhguwegagsdgygydgfgdcgycg",
            "fhdgyhdfhfgdyhhwsddgyuduuufguugwugdfgugdgooduiuduiuduuduiuiuidudiiwdiou"


        };

    /**
     * Our data, part 3.
     */
    private boolean[] mExpanded = 
        {
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false   
        };


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having private iVars in the adapter.. you should instantiate them as a `final` vairable inside the `getView()` method.. Currently inside the listener you set the new images ... but the variable points to the address of the last created button only.

Update your code to like this

```
private class EventListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    /// other things

    //private TextView textViewForDateHeader; // remove such private vars

    .. other methods

    public View getView(int position, View myView, ViewGroup parent) {
          //other code

      final ImageButton  buttonForCheckMark = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonForCheckMark);

          buttonForCheckMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonForCheckMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                //now the buttonForCheckMark refers to the imageview your instantiated above .. not the private var
               //other code
            }
        });
```

> Edit

For the highlight persist.. add a boolean array inside the adapter .

```
 private boolean highlighted[];
```

inside `EventListAdapter()` initialize it to the mTitles size too

```
  public EventListAdapter(Context context)
    {
            highlighted = new boolean[mTitles.length];
            mContext = context;
    }
```

now inside the onListener .. check highlighted[clickPos] == true .. disable it and if it false .. set it to true;
you can also use this value to persist the highlight inside the `getView()`

Comment: Thanks!!!! it is working... now, when i tap on list item, the effect of background image change is gone.. how to retain that??

Comment: check if your getView is called again when tapped .. if so store the highlight value in a bool var and in getView set the highlight position yourself

Comment: is getView called on tap ?

Comment: How do I set the highlighted position in getView() method. I am not cleared what you mean by store the highlighted value in a boolean variable...

Comment: can you accept this question and create new one.. i can add better code in that.. currently it is becoming messy

Answer (score 0):

Move the following declarations inside your `getView` method.

```
TextView textViewForDateHeader;
TextView textViewTitle;
TextView textViewDialogue;
TextView textViewHeader;
ImageButton buttonForCheckMark;
ImageButton buttonForDelete;
View buttonForRemainder;
```

Comment: Now, when i click on listitem, effects of background changing for button are gone.. it should remain na..